# Presenting 5-point Likert scale data as a percentage, rather than an average

Tags: data-visualization, likert

I'm working on a project that uses mostly descriptive statistics to show how satisfied people who visit police services are with the services at any particular station. The consumers aren't very savvy with statistics, so it's a challenge to present this data (think the police chief of a developing country).

Here I'm limited to descriptive statistics. Now, and in this case usually, I'd just take this 'very satisfied' to 'very dissatisfied' data and show a breakdown bar and the final score of all the data and average it on a 5-point scale (e.g. 4.25/5). However, the company I'm working for has been basically taking that data and putting it on a 100% scale because that's the only scale they've found that the audience can understand. 4.25/5 doesn't make sense to them, but apparently 85% out of 100% does.

My concern is... how they are interpreting this data (are they secretly interpreting it as a school grade because it's a scale they're familiar with?) and part of me wonders if it's valid methodologically to put 1/5 as 0% score and 5/5 as 100%. Any thoughts on these questions?

Comment: We have no grounds to dispute your story. Nevertheless it's puzzling. In school and outside many things are graded 1 to 5. British television viewers of a certain age remember the panellist on _Juke Box Jury_ who would repeatedly give 5/5 for new releases and I suspect there are many similar examples. Millions if not billions of sports fans know about averages, and in many systems grade point averages are standard.

Comment: I agree Nick, it's a bit puzzling, but they said they've tried to present the data on a 5 point scale and that it resulted in puzzling looks. I work in developing countries, and you really have to remember that it's a different context and that the usual assumptions don't hold.

Still, part of me thinks transforming data to a to a 100 point scale is a bad idea due to the potential for misinterpretation is even worse than "not getting it", but part of me wonders who am I to question this when they've said they've tried my suggested alternatives and it didn't work out.

Answer (score 3):

"Methodologically" it doesn't make a difference, because more or less whatever method is applied to these data will give you equivalent results, whether you code it between 1 and 5 or between 0% and 100%.

There is some controversy around whether Likert scales can be analysed as quantitative (more precisely: interval scaled) data or whether only methods for ordinal data (such as medians) should be applied, but even then it doesn't make a difference how the levels are coded. If you compute averages of the original values, you have already chosen to treat them as quantitative, so the issue has nothing to do with whether percentage scaling is used.

I think what you really want to know is not a "methodological" issue but rather a psychological one: Will the percentage scale give some people inappropriate ideas about what these values mean? I can't address that because this is really not an issue for a statistician. However, I doubt it will make a big difference.

Comment: I agree with your general stance, but the term "quantitative" is not precise enough for your point. You perhaps are alluding to discussion about how such scales are (or can be treated as if) on an interval measurement scale.

Comment: Good point, I edited that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to ask about this issue that one "can't address that because this is really not an issue for a statistician." If how the data is interpreted isn't exactly the job of a statistician, whose is it? Cause ultimately, this needs to be understood by the people making decisions and I'm wondering if people might have had ideas on how the audience will understand the data based on their own experiences.

Comment: I'd probably "half agree" with that, to some extent it *is* the job of the statistician... But the job of us statisticians is only to interpret things correctly and clearly, and I think there's nothing wrong or even intrinsically unclear about using the percentage scaling. We have a hard time if audience in their head by association make something else of the interpretation than what we have said. And this is the only problem I can imagine here.

Answer (score 0):

According to 
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/422073
to transform a score of x on Likert scale for which the minimum is a and the maximum is b to a Likert scale with min=A and Max=B, we should use the formula

Y = (B - A) * (x - a) / (b - a) + A

In your example, x = 4.5, a = 1, b = 5, A = 0, B = 100.

Thus 4.5 corresponds to

Y = 0 + (100-0)(4.5-1)/(5-1) = 350/4 = 87.5

Comment: My answer addresses "part of me wonders if it's valid methodologically to put 1/5 as 0% score and 5/5 as 100%" part of your question.

Comment: How to do it is not the question. Nor does your answer address methodological validity at all.

Comment: That link explains why that approach is valid.  Also the author thought that 4.25/5 corresponds to 85%, whereas it should actually be 81.25%.

Comment: Answers like questions should be self-contained to the extent possible. Supporting references are fine, but an answer shouldn't depend on people reading them. The text of your answer still doesn't address validity.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error BillB. Was actually quite helpful!